# How to generate UniqueID by combining characters and numbers, and apply padding in ECMAScript

Tags: javascript

I want to generate UniqueID for objects, by generating the character part of the UniqueID from ASCII values, without declaring any Arrays,  The Unique ID should start from AA01 and continue through AA99, then AB01 through AB99, then AC01 though AC99, AD01 -> AD99, -> AE01 -> AE99 ..and so on. I also need to apply padding, so the UniqueID always has 4 values like "AC08" instead of "AC8".

Below is a snippet of what I have done.

```
function genUID (a,b){
  var res="";
  var res2="";
  var res3;

   if (a=>65 && a<=90) {
      res = String.fromCharCode(a); 
          if(b=>65 && b<=90) {
              res2= String.fromCharCode(b); b++;
                 for(c=1;c<150;c++){
                    if(c<100){
                    (res3=c);
                    }
                 else { 
                   (res3= c-99);  }

                 console.log(res+""+res2+""+res3);
              }
          a++ }
}   }
```

Comment: The code you've posted is illegal as the else-clause follows the for-loop, not the if-clause.

Comment: And the problem/question (besides the invalid syntax mentioned by Quaffel) is?

Comment: thanks @Andreas, & @Quaffel . I tried other option using ```` the ID is partially generated, as the increment of the second alphabet does not occur , say, when it gets to AA105, it becomes AA6, instead of "AB6".

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58875186/edit) your question if you've fixed the syntax error. And don't hide relevant info in comments, instead add them to your question.

Comment: thanks @Andreas . I tried other option using only "If-else" but the ID is partially generated, as the increment of the second alphabet does not occur , say, when it gets to AA100, it becomes AA1, instead of "AB1".    So the problem is "what am I missing to make the ID increment properly from AA01-> AA99 -> AB01 -> AB99, AC01-> AC99, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you not making this *way* more complicated than it needs to be? Just increase a normal number, format it to four digits length by padding zeroes on the left - and then just “translate” the first two numeric digits to their character “equivalent”, by adding the difference between the character codes for `A` and `0` ...

```js
for(var i=1; i<3000; ++i) {
  var padNum = ("000"+i).substr(-4),
  uniqID =
    String.fromCharCode(padNum.charCodeAt(0)+17) +
    String.fromCharCode(padNum.charCodeAt(1)+17) +
    padNum[2] +
    padNum[3];
  
  console.log(padNum, uniqID)
}
```

Result: (Snippet console here does not show the full result, but only the last few lines)

```
0001 AA01
0002 AA02
0003 AA03
0004 AA04
0005 AA05
0006 AA06
0007 AA07
0008 AA08
0009 AA09
0010 AA10
0011 AA11
...
0099 AA99
0100 AB00
0101 AB01
0102 AB02
...
0199 AB99
0200 AC00
0201 AC01
0202 AC02
...
0998 AJ98
0999 AJ99
1000 BA00
1001 BA01
1002 BA02
...
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT @04FS. Your approach excellently solves the issue.  Though not wanting to sound ungrateful, ....any idea on how to ensure  IDs do not end with "0" ?  as it would be nicer if it goes from AA99 to AB01, instead of AB00, or AB99->AC01 without AC00.    Thanks for your anticipated comment/ideas.

Comment: That depends on how exactly you’re going to implement it. If you generate them ahead, with a loop as I did in my example, you could simply skip all loop iterations where the counter ends with a 0, by putting `if(i%10 == 0) { continue; }` as first line in the loop. You could also write a function that takes one of these UUIDs as parameter, reverses the steps above to get an integer value again, adds 1 - and one more, if the result ends in 0 - and then translates the new value back into such a UUID.